# Stop program from running when pressed different keys from the statement

Tags: c#

I have this trivia game simmilar to Who wants to be a millionare on the console.

There are 8 options, A,B,C,D which represent the answers and 1,2,3,4. which represent the help options.

I identify the key pressed with this(example):

```
string key_pressed = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
if (key_pressed.Equals("A"))
{
 //code here
}
else if (key_pressed.Equals("B"))
{
 //code here
}
```

My problem is when the user presses a diferent key from those 8. The program incresses automatically by another level(changes question). How do I fix this?

edit1.

I have this block at the end of the if,else if statements.

```
     else
{
Console.WriteLine("You need to input a valid key");
continue;
}
```

Comment: You need a while block to loop to get code and wait some instructions

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I don't know what @Jones is trying to say, but if your code executes `continue` if any other key is pressed and that is wrong, you need to show the loop around these `if`s.

Comment: see answer of @keshlam below

Comment: Thank you for your replies. All I needed is that while

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query for the key in a loop, and don't exit the loop until you get one of the keys you're looking for.

I don't code in c#, but one solution might look something like:

```
string key_pressed="";
while(key_pressed=="")
{
  string key_pressed = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
  if (key_pressed.Equals("A"))
  {
     //code here
  }
  else if (key_pressed.Equals("B"))
  {
    //code here
  }
  // else-if cases for C and D
  else
  {
    // code for the "wrong key" case. Beep, perhaps.
    key_pressed=""; // so the loop continues
  }
} // end of while loop
```

(If I was coding that in C or C++ I'd probably use break/iterate directives, and probably a do/while rather than while/do, but this is easier for a beginner to read and will do the job.)

Comment: Thank you, that `while` did all the diference

Answer (score 0):

Add an `else { }` block at the end and do whatever's appropriate for that case (e.g., print out a message reminding the user to enter a valid choice).

Comment: @USER1 OK, but please post the rest of your code, particularly the part that shows your loop construct... it's impossible to see what might be going wrong without it.

Answer (score 0):

Try a switch instead, and return in the default. Otherwise you can add an else and return there to break out of the function.

```
switch (key_pressed)
{
    case "A":
        // code here
        break;
    case "B":
        //code here
        break;
    default:
        return;
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this construction, it's the most convenient way to implement such behavior:

```
//Listen for key pressed
ConsoleKeyInfo keyPressed = Console.ReadKey(true);
switch (keyPressed.Key)
{
case ConsoleKey.A:
    {
        //A variant
        break;
    }
case ConsoleKey.B:
    {
        //B variant
        break;
    }
case ConsoleKey.C:
    {
        //C variant
        break;
    }
case ConsoleKey.D:
    {
        //D variant
        break;
    }
default:
    {
        //If a different key pressed
        break;
    }
}
```